# Alguien sabe porque me aparece un archivo de texto en el escritorio llamado "debug.log"

Tags: depuración

[image: Esto es lo que me aparece]
Si alguien me puede decir que es se lo agradecería.
Gracias.

Comment: ¿Sistema Operativo? Ni idea. ¿Aplicación usada? Ni idea. ¿Solución?  Ninguna

Answer (score 0):

No se que IDE ni lenguaje estas utilizando, ya que no das nada de información, pero el archivo "debug.log" es fruto de un error en algún programa third party que estés usando. Puedes borrarlo y no pasará nada ya que solo contiene información sobre el error que estas provocando.

PD: Para la próxima intenta dar mas información para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte de forma mas precisa.

Comment: Esto no provee una reapuesta a la pregunta. Por favor leer [answer]. Cuando tengas la suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) podrás dejar comentarios en cualquier publicación. Saludos

Comment: El IDE que uso es NetBeans y también utilizo Visual Studio Code pero no creo que eso sea lo que provoca el error. Hay alguna manera de saber que lo provoca?

Answer (score 0):

El IDE que uso es NetBeans y también utilizo Visual Studio Code pero no creo que eso sea lo que provoca el error.
Hay alguna manera de saber que lo provoca?